# Finding items that appear only one time in a Javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to find the items that appear only one time in a Javascript array. In the following array:

```
['txfa2','txfa9','txfa2','txfa1','txfa3','txfa4','txfa8','txfa9','txfa2','txfa8']
```

The result should be:

```
['txfa1','txfa3','txfa4']
```

I'm currently using the `.each()` function in jQuery and `.sort()`. Is there a smarter or better way on doing this? Do you know of any jQuery plugin that can do this in fewer lines of code.

```
<script src="../../js/jq.js"></script>
<script>
var items = ['txfa2', 'txfa9', 'txfa2', 'txfa1', 'txfa3', 'txfa4', 'txfa8', 'txfa9', 'txfa2', 'txfa8'];
var nopairs = []; //should contain only txfa1, txfa3, txfa4
var haspair = '';//contains the item which has pairs
var haspair_ctr = 0;
var nopair_ctr = 0;

var arranged = items.sort();

$(arranged).each(function(index){
    if(index != arranged.length){
        if(arranged[index] != arranged[index + 1] && arranged[index] != haspair){
            nopairs[nopair_ctr] = arranged[index];
            nopair_ctr++;

        }else{
            haspair  = arranged[index];

        }   
    }

});
console.log(nopairs);

</script>
```

Comment: Please brief what you mean by pairing in your case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A concise way to do it:

```js
function singles(array) {
  for (var index = 0, single = []; index < array.length; index++) {
    if (array.indexOf(array[index], array.indexOf(array[index]) + 1) == -1)
      single.push(array[index]);
  };
  return single;
};

var items = ['txfa2', 'txfa9', 'txfa2', 'txfa1', 'txfa3', 'txfa4', 'txfa8', 'txfa9', 'txfa2', 'txfa8'];

console.log(singles( items ))
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/C849F/

Here's the performance of the non-duplicate answers to this question (that actually work) showing this method (blue) is comparable with the other methods.

Performance: http://jsperf.com/find-array-singles/3

[image]

Comment: @Alnitak It's considerably faster than the one you presented on samples similar those in the question: http://jsperf.com/find-array-singles/3

Comment: Curious - yes, on small smallers that's fast but I'd expect mine to be faster on larger arrays as it should be O(n + nlogn) - odd that Safari is so slow, though!

Comment: Hmm, maybe it's the overhead of creating a closure in `.reduce()`

Comment: @Alnitak Yeah that is weird. I also found it odd that mine was so fast on Chrome and not Safari. I expected middle-of-the-road performance across all the browsers with mine.

Comment: This won't work in IE < 9 without an `Array.prototype.indexOf` shim.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an example using ES5's functional methods, based on using an object to count the number of times each value occurs:

```js
function uniq(a) {
  // create a map from value -> count(value)
  var counts = a.reduce(function(o, k) {
    o[k] = o[k] ? o[k] + 1 : 1;
    return o;
  }, {});

  // find those that only appeared once
  return Object.keys(counts).filter(function(k) {
    return (counts[k] === 1);
  });
}

console.log(
  uniq(['txfa2', 'txfa9', 'txfa2', 'txfa1', 'txfa3', 'txfa4', 'txfa8', 'txfa9', 'txfa2', 'txfa8'])
)
```

Working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/shyce/

Comment: Maybe using `Object.keys` instead of `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` would be better?

Comment: @Amaan `getOwnPropertyNames()` is safer.

Comment: @Alnitak use `.keys` since `o[k]` never becomes a non-enumerable property

Comment: @Raynos ah, yes, I was thinking of guarding against additions to `Object.prototype` but I see that `.keys()` does that correctly, and also correctly omits the non-enumerable properties. Thx.

Answer (score 4):

a simple approach will be making advantage of Javascript's builtin object. Let an object act as a counter for each item in the collection, then iterate over it to check which item has a counter of 1.

**it's quite fast;**

```js
var items = ['txfa2', 'txfa9', 'txfa2', 'txfa1', 'txfa3', 'txfa4', 'txfa8', 'txfa9', 'txfa2', 'txfa8'],
  result = [],
  i, 
  k, 
  container = {};

for (i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
  if (items[i] in container) {
    container[items[i]]++;
  } else {
    container[items[i]] = 1;
  }
}

for (k in container) {
  if (container[k] == 1) {
    result.push(k);
  }
}

console.log(result)
```

Comment: S/he is asking about elements that appear exactly once, for example `txfa2` should **not** be present in the result.

Answer (score 1):

By "find the unique items" I believe you mean "find items that are not repeated" (as compared to "find distinct values")? Also, I don't understand why your `haspair` variable is a string: your sample data has more than one pair in it. Anyway...

There are lots of ways to do this, but I'd use an object to make a count for each distinct values. That makes it easy to generate an array of the non-repeated items and an array of the repeated items, and an array of the distinct values. Obviously if you don't need all three you omit the ones you don't care about, but I've shown all three below which is why it may look a bit longer than you wanted. Of course if you want a count of how many are in any category you just use the array length.

```
var items = ['txfa2', 'txfa9', 'txfa2', 'txfa1', 'txfa3', 'txfa4', 'txfa8', 'txfa9', 'txfa2', 'txfa8'];

var working = {},
    hasPairs = [],
    noPairs = [],
    distinct = [],
    i, k;

for (i=0; i < items.length; i++)
   if (working.hasOwnProperty(items[i]))
      working[items[i]]++;
   else
      working[items[i]] = 1;

for (k in working) {
   if (working[k] > 1)
      hasPairs.push(k);
   else
      noPairs.push(k);
   distinct.push(k);
}
```

Note: I've written the above with plain JavaScript, without using newer array functions that might not be supported by older browsers. Obviously you can take the basic algorithm and use jQuery to iterate through the initial array and/or the properties of `working`, or you can use [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) if you don't care about IE < 9, etc.

Answer (score -1):

```
/** 
 * Array.uniq();
 *
 * @author: Alexander Guiness
 * @param: {Array}
 * @return: {Array} An array of unique values
 * @licence: MIT
 * @use: Array.uniq([1,1,1,1,2,2,2,4,5,5,4]); //1,2,4,5
 * @date: Mon Jul 26 10:00:00 2011
*/

(function($) {
    'use strict';
    if(!$.uniq) {
        $.uniq = function(array) {
            if(Object.prototype.toString.call(array) !== '[object Array]')
                 return -1; 

            var i = array.length;
            array.sort();

            while(i--) {
                if(array[i] == array[i-1]) {
                    array.splice(i, 1);
                }
            }
            return array;
       }

    }
}(Array));
```

see the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/2b7Wq/2/)

or use: `jQuery.unique([]);`

Comment: The example returns `1,2,4,5,4`